# QMap Datatype in QML basic usage?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

Assume I have a simple QMap declared and Initialized with values inside C++ and correctly exposed to QML.

> C++

```cpp
QMap<QString, QMap<QString, QString>> airflow_buttons_;
//simple getter
[[nodiscard]] QMap<QString, QMap<QString, QString>> airflow_buttons() const;
```

> QML

```
console.log(ClimateModel.airflow_buttons);
```

prints the following

`(qrc:/Climate/AirflowButtons.qml:24)  - QVariant(QMap<QString,QMap<QString,QString>>, QMap(("left", QMap(("top_air", "NOT_ACTIVE")))))`

It is giving me a [QVariant](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qvariant.html). I have no idea how to convert it to my desired Map with the desired values?

I want to use it as a simple JavaScript Map.

```
console.log(ClimateModel.airflow_buttons["left"]["top_air"]); //Should print "NOT_ACTIVE" 
console.log(ClimateModel.airflow_buttons["left"]);            //Should print the Map contents
```

The current error message is `[debug] expression for onCompleted (qrc:/Climate/AirflowButtons.qml:24)  - undefined`

Example on what i want to achieve in plain Javascript

```
var myMap = {x: "Test", y: "Test 2"};
myMap["z"] = "Test 3";
console.log(myMap["z"]);                 //prints "Test 3"
console.log(JSON.stringify(myMap["z"])); //prints the map contents
```

How can I achieve this trivial task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using a QVariantMap all the way:

```
QVariantMap airflow_buttons = {
    {"left", QVariantMap{
         {"top_air", "NOT ACTIVE"}}}
};
```

---

btw, in QML you can also do this if you fancy:

```
console.log(ClimateModel.airflow_buttons.left.top_air)
```

Comment: Didn't test it yet but can you explain to me why I have to use the QVariantMap and can't use the QMap datatype or a link to know which types I can use and which not? Thanks

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#qvariantlist-and-qvariantmap-to-javascript-array-and-object _The QML engine provides automatic type conversion between QVariantList and JavaScript arrays, and between QVariantMap and JavaScript objects._

Comment: QVariantMap is your friend. We use it all the time.

Comment: Thanks @iam_peter i will start using them, im still a bit confused because QList without Variant did work(same approach) and QVariantMap didnt but I guess i will just start using the Variants and accept it without knowing why some work and some dont

Comment: @Ojav https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#sequence-type-to-javascript-array _Certain C++ sequence types are supported transparently in QML to behave like JavaScript Array types._